# Elixir Phoenix Restful to websocket API

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, phoenix-channels

RESTful to websocket API question: I want to enable a RESTful api that interfaces with websockets.

I have some hardware that maintains a WS connection to my Phx.server, and I would like to allow other clients to hit the phx.server via a RESTful api and interact with WS connected hardware.

The part I have not figured out is the response for RESTful call, i.e. the http response. Suppose I want a client to be able to request the current temperature from a sensor on the hardware connected via WS.

I can broadcast to the WS via the controller using Phoenix.Endpoint.broadcast(topic, event, msg), but I want to “wait” for a response so that I can send the temp back in the HTTP response from the client. Any suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but I would try something similar to this:

send the `conn` struct to your socket device which will include it inside the `response`.

And implement a `handle_in` callback inside your Channel which will handle the response from your Socket, with the conn struct, so that you can reuse it, to send the response to your HTTP client:

```
  # Send the connection to your socket
  Phoenix.Endpoint.broadcast(topic, event, %{"conn" => conn})

  #
  def handle_in("temperature_response", %{"temperature" => t, "conn" => conn}, socket) do
    render(conn, "temperature.json", %{"temperature" => t})
    {:noreply, socket}
  end
```

Comment: I started down another path that uses Registry as a bridge between different apis. I am sure there are multiple ways of solving the problem. Once I have finished and tested I will post the work as it has been a good learning experience for me.

Comment: Definitly, would like to check it out later